# Download csv in shiny using inputs as data frame name parts

Tags: r, shiny

There are existing `data.frames` that are called: `active_acc_newacc`, `active_acc_oldacc`, `inactive_acc_newacc`, `inactive_acc_oldacc`. They all contain a lot of rows and columns. I created a code with Shiny, where the user chooses with a radio button if they want to download active or inactive   and old, or new. When they click on `Download`, a csv file needs to be downloaded. The csv should be the content of the dataframe, for example the user chooses Active and new, then the dataframe called `active_acc_newacc` should be downloaded as a csv, another example is if they chose Inactive and old, then the dataframe called `inactive_acc_oldacc`dataframe should be downloaded as csv.

In this example, `active_acc_newacc` contains this sample data:

```
structure(list(Alpha = c(0.192491906485068, -1.44670180633351, 
-0.323180534047634, 1.62229611652493, -0.689024123596357, 2.04212222261495, 
0.94377911190294, 2.0819268787991, 1.91711727878331, -0.414812239592928
), Beta = c(1.03285349943413, -1.67856959219527, 0.157549690345431, 
1.48913611644558, -0.0757895625491196, 1.27178094415894, 0.641673407672177, 
0.800761254937157, 1.86265922566283, -0.545356026768875), Gamma = c(1.52068837343838, 
-3.61004798325456, -1.35857038834863, 3.48938862108709, -3.05109504225968, 
6.5047022366346, 2.50727319977214, 5.31673927920108, 3.69096202696173, 
-1.03802874828505)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have the following in the ui.R, requesting input:

```
ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Account classification"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          radioButtons("account_status","Select account status", choices=c("Active","Inactive","Include both"),selected = "Active"),
          br(),
          radioButtons("account_age","Select account creation time", choices=c("old","new","Created any time"),selected = "new")

            ),   

      mainPanel(
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

       )
      )
    )
```

I created the following server.R

```
server = function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
  switch(input$account_status,
       "Active" = active_acc,
       "Inactive" = inactive_acc,
       "Include both" = NULL)

  switch(input$account_age,
       "old" = oldacc,
       "new" = newacc,
       "Created any time" = all)
  })

  dfname <- reactive({
  paste(input$account_status,input$account_age, sep='_')
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.csv', sep='') },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(dfname(), file)
  }
)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, when I hit the "download" button, it downloads a csv that contains this (in case of inactive and old are selected) :

"","x"

"1","Inactive_old”

So only the text is written out.

I modified the code and sometimes what Download does is downloading the ui.R radio button page as an html.

How shall I write the codes in order to get a successful csv download?

Comment: Once typos and missing brackets are fixed the app is working. "it does not work" is also not very specific.

Comment: Can you please help me in specific, where I misplaced the brackets?

Comment: I edited your code. Now it is working. I am not exactly sure what do you expect to have in your csv file.

Comment: Thanks. Is now downloads a html with the ui.R when clicking the button.
Let us suppose that you chose "Active" and "new". Here, the csv that should be downloaded is a file that comes from a dataframe called: "active_acc_newacc"

Comment: Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  /Users/xxxxxxxx/shiny/account_classification/server.R:43:0: unexpected end of input

41: 
42: 
   ^

Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing 

/Users/xxxxxxxx/account_classification/server.R
  [No stack trace available]
Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/account_classification/server.R

Comment: Are you looking for this: `output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste0(input$account_status, "acc_", input$account_age, "acc", '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(dfname(), file)
      }
    )`?

Comment: Is there a way that I rename the input after is is given by the user? 
The dataframe that I want to download is called "active_acc_newacc".
How can I set the code as input$account_status is "active" when the user chooses "Active"? This would solve my problems.
Here:
switch(input$account_status,
       "Active" = active_acc,
       "Inactive" = inactive_acc,
       "Include both" = NULL)
I exactly try to do that.

Comment: if I use `filename = function() { paste0(tolower(input$account_status), "_", "acc_", input$account_age, "acc", '.csv', sep='') },` when I clink on the download button I have a csv. file called `active_acc_newacc.csv`.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, and if you create a dataframe with the name "active_acc_newacc" with some value in it, and then you click the Download button, what happens? My issue is that it is not the content of the dataframe that is written out in the csv file.

Comment: The column name is x, and the first row is `Active_new`. What do you expect?

Comment: There are existing dataframes that are called: active_acc_newacc, active_acc_oldacc, inactive_acc_newacc, inactive_acc_oldacc, etc.
They all contain a lot of rows and columns.
The user chooses with a radio button if they want to download active or inactive, old, or new.
When they click on Download, a csv needs to be downloaded.
The csv should be the content of the dataframe, for example the user chooses Active and new, then the dataframe called "active_acc_newacc" should be downloaded as a csv.

Comment: For this I need the server.R code and that is what i am looking for

Comment: "They all contain a lot of rows and columns" where is this information in your post?

Comment: It is included now.

Comment: I mean is it is impossible for us to download a csv file with rows and columns when in your shiny example you have no datasets. You don't provide an actual dataset in your example.

Comment: Thanks, now I provided a sample dataset.

Comment: Include it using `dput()`.

Comment: I made a sampe with dput()

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Activeacc_newacc <- structure(list(Alpha = c(0.192491906485068, -1.44670180633351, 
-0.323180534047634, 1.62229611652493, -0.689024123596357, 2.04212222261495, 
0.94377911190294, 2.0819268787991, 1.91711727878331, -0.414812239592928
), Beta = c(1.03285349943413, -1.67856959219527, 0.157549690345431, 
1.48913611644558, -0.0757895625491196, 1.27178094415894, 0.641673407672177, 
0.800761254937157, 1.86265922566283, -0.545356026768875), Gamma = c(1.52068837343838, 
-3.61004798325456, -1.35857038834863, 3.48938862108709, -3.05109504225968, 
6.5047022366346, 2.50727319977214, 5.31673927920108, 3.69096202696173, 
-1.03802874828505)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Account classification"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("account_status","Select account status", choices=c("Active","Inactive","Include both"),selected = "Active"),
      br(),
      radioButtons("account_age","Select account creation time", choices=c("old","new","Created any time"),selected = "new")

    ),   

    mainPanel(
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$account_status,
           "Active" = active_acc,
           "Inactive" = inactive_acc,
           "Include both" = NULL)

    switch(input$account_age,
           "old" = oldacc,
           "new" = newacc,
           "Created any time" = all)
  })

  dfname <- reactive({
    test <- paste0(input$account_status, "acc_", input$account_age, "acc", sep='')
    get(test)
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(dfname(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```